# starting a website project in python and django in windows 10

Tags: python, django

Whenever I type django-admin start project project name the console returns Django-admin : The term 'Django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- Django-admin start project emart
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException.
  ```

Comment: it is `djang-admin` (with lowercase).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem And that too in `kebab-case` :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `$ django-admin startproject mysite`

Also, make sure to have the Python envirovment you want to use (the one with Django installed) active

Check the official [documentation for Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/)